# Azure SQL Query Editor vs Management Studio

Tags: sql-server, azure, azure-sql-database, ssms

I'm pretty new to azure and cloud computing in general and would like to ask your help in figuring out issue.

Issue was first seen when we had webpage that time outs due to sql timeout set to (30 seconds).

First thing I did was connect to the Production database using MS SQL management studio 2014 (Connected to the azure prod db)

Ran the stored procedure being used by the low performing page but got the return less than 0 seconds. This made me confused since what could be causing the issue.

By accident i also tried to run the same query in the Azure SQL query editor and was shock that it took 29 seconds to run it.

My main question is why is there a difference between running the query in azure sql query editor vs Management studio. This is the exact same database.

DTU usage is at 98% and im thingking there is a performance issue with the stored proc but want to know first why sql editor is running the SP slower than Management studio.

Current azure db has 50 dtu's.

Comment: Sounds like parameter sniffing. I can't believe it's still a thing!

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid im currently reading about parameter sniffing and considering the impact but the question still stands if there is a parameter sniffing issue why does it not occur when i use the management studio? are you saying sniffing is done in the client and not in the actual server? we are talking about the same server just different clients

Comment: What I discovered was that different clients (libraries) use different SET settings. So a query run from EF uses a different SET ARITHABORT to a query run from SSMS. That means the entire query gets a different 'fingerprint', which means it uses a different (possibly new) cached query plan. Parameter sniffing is about using a bad cached query plan, which is _usually_ due to a bad initial set of parameters. I hope that makes sense.

Comment: What DAL does your webapp use? EF? Because the usual order of events is that an app using EF is slow then you run it in SSMS and it's fast. Again - with parameter sniffing it's not really the client or the library, it's just that they use slightly different SET settings, giving the query a new fingerprint and forcing a new plan

Answer (score 0):

Two guesses (posting query plans will help get you an answer for situations like this):

1. SQL Server has various session-level settings.  For example, there is one to determine if you should use ansi_nulls behavior (vs. the prior setting from very old versions of SQL Server).  There are others for how identifiers are quoted and similar.  Due to legacy reasons, some of the drivers have different default settings.  These different settings can impact which query plans get chosen, in the limit.  While they won't always impact performance, there is a chance that you get a scan instead of a seek on some query of interest to you.
2. The other main possible path for explaining this kind of issue is that you have a parameter sniffing difference.  SQL's optimizer will peek into the parameter values used to pick a better plan (hoping that the value will represent the average use case for future parameter values).  Oracle calls this bind peeking - SQL calls it parameter sniffing.  Here's the post I did on this some time ago that goes through some examples:
   https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/queryoptteam/2006/03/31/i-smell-a-parameter/

I recommend you do your experiments and then look at the query store to see if there are different queries or different plans being picked.  You can learn about the query store and the SSMS UI here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/performance/monitoring-performance-by-using-the-query-store?view=sql-server-2017

For this specific case, please note that the query store exposes those different session-level settings using "context settings".  Each unique combination of context settings will show up as a different context settings id, and this will inform how query texts are interpreted.  In query store parlance, the same query text can be interpreted different ways under different context settings, so two different context settings for the same query text would imply two semantically different queries.

Hope that helps - best of luck on your perf problem

Comment: I am looking into the data given but im not sure if the question is clear due to the edit done by one user. This is the same database we are talking about. If its a parameter sniffing issue would it matter which client app i would use to connect? its the same azure database and the same procedure.

Comment: Parameter sniffing generally would be client agnostic for the same command from different clients.  There are potentially different behaviors, however, based on which client you are using.  You have to go check what queries/plans get submitted.  (which you can do with query store to validate).